# jquery selector: child elements of the same class inside divs of different classes

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

There are two divs with classes ".div1" and ".div2".
Each of them contains the same code - the same elements with the same class names.
If I need to set/get a value of an element inside one of the divs, how do I refer to those elements?
I try the following:

```
var hostPopup = "hostdiv" + selectedPopup + " "; // where selectedPopup = "1" or "2"
$(hostPopup + '.testColor').css('background-color', rgba);
$(hostPopup + '.testColorText').css({'color': rgba, '-webkit-filter': 'invert(100%)', 'filter': 'invert(100%)'});
```

It does not work. But if I use the hostPopup to specify the host div only for one operation - that works for the first line here:

```
$(hostPopup + '.testColor').css('background-color', rgba);
$('.testColorText').css({'color': rgba, '-webkit-filter': 'invert(100%)', 'filter': 'invert(100%)'});
```

Works!

Here is an example of a piece of my html:

```
<div class="hostdiv1" style="padding: 0;"> <!-- hostdiv2 has exactly the same code in it -->
    <div class="NamesDiv nameTypesDiv" style="background-color: dimgray;">
    <div class="namesClass">
        <b>1.</b> Add names
    </div>
    <div class="testColor" style="background-color: rgb(124,124,124); color: white;"><p class="testColorText">Test</p></div>
    <div class="rangeDiv" style="height: 120px;">
    <div class="rangeBars"><input type="range" class="rangeR" min="0" max="100" value="50" tabindex="0"></input>
    <output for="rangeR" class="outR outRange">50</output></div>
```

So, why $(".nodeDiv1class .itsinnerelementclass").'action'... does not wish to work with itsinnerelementclass element that is located somewhere inside the element with class of nodeDiv1class ?

Comment: The period character is missing from your first class selector (`"div" + selectedPopup + " "`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a dot at the start of `hostPopup` so that jQuery knows that it's a class.